# What's a good, lightweight DWG viewer for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, viewer, autocad, dwg

I'm looking for a light-weight AutoCAD DWG viewer. I don't want to install the 180MB TrueView just to open a DWG file every once in a long while...

Comment: It doesn't have to be free if it has a trial and is well-recommended (I'll buy!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some info from a non-user of CAD:

There is a whole bunch of CAD viewers in [here](http://www.freecad.com/CAD_Viewers/).
The list doesn't include [Free eDrawings Viewer](http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/pages/products/DWG-DXF-Viewer.html).

[AcadPVI Shell Extension](http://jmsware.com/info-acadpvi.html) adds the AutoCAD preview and version to the right-click context menu in Windows Explorer.
[AutoCAD Version Explorer](http://jmsware.com/info-ave.html) (AVE) is a stand-alone program that provides an Explorer-like interface to quickly view AutoCAD preview and version information.

Comment: +1 for the eDrawings Viewer from SolidWorks--that works for me

Comment: eDrawings Viewer from SolidWorks is not free

Answer (score 3):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) claims to view DWG files, and it's both free and small. It's a very good image viewer but I'll confess to not knowing how well it's DWG support fares, or to what version of DWG it supports.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this link--Irfanview looks awesome. CAD support is $USD48 because you have to buy a DLL to make the plugin usable

Comment: but in irfanview they used a third party plugin which require us to register first.

Answer (score -1):

[LX-Viewer](http://lx-viewer.sourceforge.net/) is open source and light weight viewer. Not sure about windows 7 compatibility

Comment: The Windows version appears to be 6 years old so I'll pass for now, thanks though!